# Why two slice have same address, but not have same value in Golang?

Tags: go

In go source code we can see this type declare:

```golang
type slice struct {
    array unsafe.Pointer
    len   int
    cap   int
}
```

So I thought `s := make([]string, 0)` is equal to `s := &slice{}`.

But when I tried to run these codes, I am confused:

```golang
s := make([]int, 0, 2)
s2 := s
s = append(s, 10)
fmt.Printf("%v, %p\n", s, s)
fmt.Printf("%v, %p\n", s2, s2)
```

I found `s` `s2` have same address, but not have same value.

These two slice are obviously like:

```golang
array := [2]int{10}
s := &slice{
  array: unsafe.Pointer(&array),
  len: 1,
  cap: 2,
}
s2 := &slice{
  array: unsafe.Pointer(&array),
  len: 0,
  cap: 2,
}
```

They have same array pointer, but they are two different `slice`.

In normal way, when I run `fmt.Printf("%p\n", s)` it should print `s`` address.

But Golang seems like print `s.array`, which is array`s address.

Comment: Please read the two blog post about slices and append and do the tour of Go once more. Stop using package unsafe you won't learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

You actually are manipulating the same underlying array. It's just that the value of `s2.len` is still 0, and that's [used by the `fmt` package when printing its value](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/fmt/print.go;l=908;drc=4a0a2b33dfa3c99250efa222439f2c27d6780e4a).

It's also worth pointing out that when using the `%p` verb with a slice, it's documented to print the:

> address of 0th element in base 16 notation, with leading 0x

From https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#hdr-Printing. Your assumption that it should print the address of the slice struct itself is contrary to the documented behavior.

---

Here's your code snippet expanded a bit to more clearly illustrate what's happening:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func printSlices(slices ...[]int) {
    for _, s := range slices {
        hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
        fmt.Printf("%v, %p, %v\n", s, s, hdr)
    }
}

func main() {
    s := make([]int, 0, 2)
    s2 := s

    fmt.Println("Add two values to s...")
    s = append(s, []int{10, 20}...)

    printSlices(s, s2)

    fmt.Println("Add a value to s2...")
    s2 = append(s2, 30)

    printSlices(s, s2)

    fmt.Println("Add another value to s, exceeding it's capacity, causing a new backing array to be allocated")
    s = append(s, 40)

    printSlices(s, s2)
}
```

Output

```
Add two values to s...
[10 20], 0xc00001c030, &{824633835568 2 2}
[], 0xc00001c030, &{824633835568 0 2}
Add a value to s2...
[30 20], 0xc00001c030, &{824633835568 2 2}
[30], 0xc00001c030, &{824633835568 1 2}
Add another value to s, exceeding it's capacity, causing a new backing array to be allocated
[30 20 40], 0xc000102000, &{824634777600 3 4}
[30], 0xc00001c030, &{824633835568 1 2}
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ifXpGMjHzWR)